# Minikube expose service nginx proxy manager

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

I'm learning and trying to setup minikube in an ubuntu server to manage and deploy applications.

I'm using nginx proxy manager application to manage the proxy's in the server.

I've followed this [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#create-a-second-deployment) to setup ingress with NGINX Ingress Controller, and everyhing works fine, when I run `curl *minikube_ip*:service_port` I get

```
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: web-746c8679d4-zhtll
```

Now, the problem is, I'm trying to expose this to the outside world by adding a proxy host in nginx proxy manager that proxies *domain_name.com* to the `*minikube_ip*:service_port` but it just keeps giving me 504 Gateway Time-out.

here's the ingress yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hello-world.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web
                port:
                  number: 8080
          - path: /v2
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web2
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

When I run `kubectl get svc`

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          2d12h
web          NodePort    10.104.186.135   <none>        8080:31806/TCP   2d12h
```

In my hosts file

```
*minikube_ip* hello-world.info
```

I suspect it might be related to the minikube docker container not being in the same network as the nginx proxy manager container, but I really don't know how to solve this, help pls

Comment: Did you create an Ingress resource which exposes a the service port externally? Can you post the YAML here?

Comment: just added it to the post @pnavk

Comment: Can you also provide the output of `kubectl get svc`? And is hello-world.info been defined in your etc/hosts file?

Comment: @pnavk yes just added that info

Answer (score 0):

A `NodePort` type service can be accessed via the IP Address of the node(s) running in your cluster. Kubernetes will route the request to the proper pod based on the IP and port provided.

If you want to use a host name defined in an `Ingress` resource instead of the IP Address and port, change your service to `type=ClusterIP`.

Try running the following command to change your service to type ClusterIP:

```
kubectl patch svc web -p '{"spec": {"type": "ClusterIP"}}'
```

Wait for an `EXTERNAL-IP` to be assigned to the service, you can watch using `kubectl get svc --watch`

Update your hosts file with the `EXTERNAL-IP` value instead of the *minikube_ip*

Finally, try visiting `hello-world.info` in the browser

Comment: thank you, it didn't work, the `EXTERNAL-IP` kept with`<none>`. I tried `kubectl patch svc web -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["192.168.0.194"]}}'` and added `192.168.0.194 hello-world.info` to my hosts file but still doesn't work. Right now I can only get the output with the `curl minikube_ip:svcPort`